# Stop ScatterViewItem from rotating with 1 finger

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, scatterview

By default, when dragging or throwing a `ScatterViewItem` around, it would rotate slightly also. Is there any way to limit this behavior such that rotation is permitted only when at least 2 fingers is doing the current manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having tested it: You should be able to set the [`SingleInputRotationMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.controls.scattercontentcontrolbase.singleinputrotationmode.aspx) property to `SingleInputRotationMode.Disabled`.